# Get document by insertedId MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 collections in the mongoDB database: books and authors.

in a book document there is a record of an author from the authors collection.

how can I get the author document By insertedId?

book document example:

```
_id: new ObjectId("6350f2eaf7dd9bfc16392a19"),
    name: 'the teacher',
    discreption: 'very good book',
    published: '1.1.2022',
    author: {
      acknowledged: true,
      insertedId: new ObjectId("6350f2e9f7dd9bfc16392a17")
    },
    pages: 500
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can populate the author document by

```
book.find().populate({path: "author.insertedId"}),
```

else

```
db.collectionName.find().populate("author.insertedId"),
```

else

```
db.book.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "author",
      "localField": "author.insertedId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "author"
    }
  }
]
```

> https://mongoplayground.net/p/dSmT3kbwBaV

Comment: Thanks! what eggzakly the difference between ```.population()``` and ```$lookup```?